# Cancan error while authorize on nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

I'm trying to set access to nested resource (specialty) ex. ".../companies/:id/specialties". Accessing company that doesn't belong to me work fine. But I can't access to my specialties. Please help me, because I've spent 4 hours searching the solution without any result. 
 I have the  following:

CanCan 1.6.9

```
//routes.rb
  resources :companies do
    resources :specialties
  end
```

//ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.super_admin?
    can :open, :admin_pages
  else
    cannot :open, :admin_pages
  end

  can [:edit, :update, :destroy], Company do |company|
    company.try(:admin) == user
  end

  can :manage, Specialty 
  end
end
```

//companies_controller.rb

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def new
    @company = current_user.build_company
  end

  def create
    @company = current_user.build_company params[:company]
    if @company.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: I18n.t('notices.company_successfully_created')
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @company = Company.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @company = current_user.company
    if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
      redirect_to root_path, notice: I18n.t('notices.company_successfully_updated')
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

end
```

//specialties_controller.rb

```
class SpecialtiesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :company
  load_and_authorize_resource  through: :company

  before_filter :company, except: [:destroy]

  def index
    @specialties = @company.specialties
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { 
        resource = params[:resource_type]=='user' ? User.new : Profile.new 
        render :json => {:success => true, :html => (render_to_string '_specialties_list.html.slim', :locals => {:resource => resource})} 
      }
      format.html {}
    end
  end

  def new
    @specialty = @company.specialties.build
  end

  def create
    @specialty = @company.specialties.build params[:specialty]
    if @specialty.save
      redirect_to company_specialties_path, notice: I18n.t('notices.specialty_successfully_created')
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @specialty = Specialty.find params[:id]
  end

  def edit
    @specialty = Specialty.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @specialty = Specialty.find params[:id]
    if @specialty.update_attributes(params[:specialty])
      redirect_to company_specialties_path, notice: I18n.t('notices.specialty_successfully_updated')
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @specialty = Specialty.find(params[:id])
    @specialty.destroy
    redirect_to company_specialties_path
  end

  private

    def company
      @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end

end
```

Comment: Is any particular action throwing an error? What is the stack trace. Use pastebin to paste the stack trace and reply with the url, if you intend to do so.

Comment: For example (company with id = 3 is mine) http://localhost:3000/companies/3/specialties doesn't give the access while I can access http://localhost:3000/companies/3/edit and I cant access (and it's as I expect to) http://localhost:3000/companies/2/edit so I cant access anything nested in company resource

Comment: I recieve "You are not authorized to access this page."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ability file, you have given only [:edit, :update, :destroy] access for a company's admin to that same company.

When he tries to access any action in the specialities controller, the first load_and_authorize_call :company will try to READ the company. After reading the company, it will find the speciality through the company and check if the user has rights for the particular action on the speciality.

In this case, the user has all permissions to speciality but does not have read permission for company, so the problem

So add :read permissions or give all permissions using :manage to the company's admin.

```
can [:read, :edit, :update, :destroy], Company do |company|
  company.try(:admin) == user
end
```